# Why does this Boolean statement in Ruby give an error?

Tags: ruby, syntax, boolean-expression

This is probably simple, but I don't understand why this statement isn't valid Ruby code:

```
3.>5 || 3.>2 
SyntaxError: unexpected tINTEGER, expecting end-of-input
```

Why this one is:

```
3.>5 || 3.> #this seems nonsensical
=> false
```

And why by my book this one seems to give a misleading answer

```
3.>5 || 3.>(2)
=> false
```

Yet, this one gives the "right" answer

```
3.>(5) || 3.>(2)
=> true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion here is due to using `.` to make Ruby parse the comparisons as method calls, rather than the more normal binary operator such as `3 > 2`. In Ruby operators such as `>` are ultimately [handled as methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-3E), but the parser has special cases to allow you to use the more familiar syntax.

If you imagine there is a method called `gt` on integers, and you rewrite your examples using it instead of `>` it might be clearer what it happening.

Your first example, `3.>5 || 3.>2`, will be equivalent to:

```
3.gt 5 || 3.gt 2
```

which Ruby tries to parse as

```
3.gt (5 || 3.gt) 2
```

That `2` at the end is the `unexpected tINTEGER` that Ruby complains about.

The second example, `3.>5 || 3.>` will be parsed as something like this:

```
3.gt (5 || 3.gt)
```

This seems nonsensical because we know that `gt` is really the binary operator `>` and that it should have a second operator. Since Ruby is parsing it as if it was a method it has no way of knowing how many arguments there should be. As far as the parser knows the `gt` method may not expect any arguments (we could have monkey patched `>` to not expect an argument). Since the evaluation of the expression `5 || 3.>` short circuits to `5`, the `3.>` part is never executed so no error occurs.

If you write the same expression but without using `.`, the Ruby parser knows that this is a binary operator and will expect the second operator:

```
eval '3>5 || 3 >'
SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
3>5 || 3 >
          ^
```

The last example, `3.>(5) || 3.>(2)`, would be parsed as:

```
3.gt(5) || 3.gt(2)
```

Because of the parentheses there is no ambiguity and it is clear that the `2` is an argument to the method call, so you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is space sensitive and, unlike the syntax highlighter used in this website, Ruby employs "maximum munch" when parsing operators.

`3.<` is different from `3. <`, because `.<` parses as "send the < message to the integer 3."

Add a space. Better, never leave a dangling dot, for just this reason, and code `3.0 < 1`.

Next, `3.>5 || 3.>(2)` parses as `3.>(5 || 3.>(2))`, because of Ruby's magical disappearing parentheses. Follow your style guide, and add spaces around almost all binary operators. The few idiomatic ones where you shouldn't are `.`, `.&`, `..`, `**`, etc...